# NGXS typed raw state value

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I cannot find an example in the NGXS documentation on how to type the state object.

I want to type the return value of the snapshot method of Store.

For example

```
this.store.snapshot().SOME_STATE_SLICE
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the slice you want to take a snapshot of it and it will be typed, for example if you have this state:

```
interface UserStateModel {
  readonly name: string;
}

export const USER_STATE_TOKEN = new StateToken<UserStateModel>('user');

@State<UserStateModel>({
  name: USER_STATE_TOKEN,
})
export class UserState {
  @Selector()
  static name(state: UserStateModel) {
    return state.name;
  }
}
```

You can then in your component do:

```
const name = this.store.selectSnapshot(UserState.name);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is cool. I can also do

`const user = this.store.selectSnapshot(UserState);`

Which will return the user object from the state.

But then, is it possible to type the return type of .snapshot()?

Comment: In order to select the whole user state object I edited my answer to separate the state token into a const and export it because you can't use UserState inside selectSnapshot, rather you need to use the state token, for example:
const user = this.store.selectSnapshot(USER_STATE_TOKEN);

Comment: Thanks, just to confirm the below works

`const user = this.store.selectSnapshot(UserState);`

Comment: Most welcome, weird I tried it and didn't work on my side, anyway glad it works now, please consider marking my answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: My version is  ` "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.5",`.

Not yet, I am still wondering if snapshot can be typed. If there are no more suggestions, I will mark it.

Thanks a lot